# Store Application specific Data using Google App Script not Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

**Purpose:** If you read the first paragraph of the following link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata 
Now as you can see there is no option to do this using AppScript. I want to try creating an Application Data Folder using Google Sheets editor.

Is this possible? If not, am I missing something? Is my logic wrong?

Comment: It is possible to access the drive api from apps script using advanced Google services or urlfetch. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You can use any Drive API method in Apps Script by enabling the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)**

The syntax would be
`Drive.Files.insert(resource, mediaData, optionalArgs)`

**2. You can perform an [Url fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) request**

Whereby the syntax is
`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`

and the url and options can be deduced from the [method description](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

**UPDATE**

A sample how to create a file in the application folder with url fetch:
Code.gs

```
function uploadToSharedDrive(){
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&uploadType=resumable"; 
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob('This is the content!'); 
  var metaData = {
    'name' :'config.json',
    'parents' :["appDataFolder"]
  }
  params = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()   
    },
    contentType:  'application/json',    
    method: 'post',
    payload: JSON.stringify(metaData),
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var data = blob.getBytes();
  var params2 = {
    method: "put",
    payload: data,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  location = response.getHeaders().Location;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(location, params2);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())   
}
```

For this code to work correctly, you need to [edit the manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests) and provide the necessary [scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest).

manifest.js:

```
{
...
   "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
...
}
```

Keep in mind that the file you create will not be accessible outside of the App  - this is intended behavior.

Comment: I really don't understand what was explained on top, I am new to appscript and I am confused by the above explanation. @ziganotschka

Comment: I assume that you know how to use the Drive API? So what I tried to explain is that you can make calls to the Drive API from inside Apps Script. It is just called `Drive` instead of `Drive API`, but it offers you the same methods like the Drive API`. Please refer to the linked documentation to see how to enable and use `Drive`. If you still have questions after this, please specify what exactly is not clear.

Comment: Enabling the Drive API is not the problem, I am finding it difficult to create a application data folder which is hidden to users.. Basically when a User installs an app, a folder inside that app is created which is not accessible or visible to the users. 
I want to create that folder which is only accessible by a developer.

Comment: Are you able to perform this request successfully with the Drive API without Apps Script?

Comment: No I have not performed this request without appscript.

Comment: As you can draw from the samples in the documentation you linked, you need to perform a resumable or multipart upload in order to specify both metadata and the content of the file and you need to specify `appDataFolder` as a parent. I will update my answer with a sample how to do in Apps Script, but to gain a deeper understanding for the code,you would need to understand first how this request is working with the API.